# Spring Tool Suite doesn't show new project in browser after delete the old one

Tags: java, spring, project, spring-tool-suite, java-ee-8

I had an old project in STS, then I deleted it and created the new one with the same project name. I create controller class showed below:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("login")
public String login() {
    return "login";
}
}
```

I have .html file also: **index.html** and **login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>INDEX</title>
</head>
<body>
    DANIEL---Index.
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>LOGIN</title>
</head>
<body>
    DANIEL---Login.
</body>
</html>
```

What I expect to be showed in browser is just DANIEL---index and DANIEL---login, but in fact, it showed the content of the old project:

[image]

Although I deleted metadata folder and change to another workplace, but it seems not effect. Please help me.

I captured STS screen:
[image]
[image]

Comment: please post screenshot of you sts projects

Comment: Could it be that you just have spring-security in your pom file and that automatically sets up and redirect to login page?

Comment: It's possible. When I type localhost:8080 and enter, it redirect automatically to localhost:8080/login. If so, what should I do with pom file now??

Answer (score 1):

When you have spring-security in your classpath it will automatically set up redirect to login with the default username being `user` and the default password will be printed in the console at the startup.

You can specify a different password in application.properties
`spring.security.user.password=password`

You can of course remove spring-security dependency from pom file and the login page will go away.

Or you can set it up like explained here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it base on what you showed me, but I didn't found the idea say that my classpath will automatically set up redirect to login page in your suggested reference. Could you show me more clearly?

Comment: you just need to read about Spring Security and how it works, I wouldn't be able to explain it all here - you can either use the official Documentation, or I really like the book Spring Security in Action from Manning